# Cannot Use React Routes on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku

I am working on a school project deploying React + SpringBoot + AWS RDS to Heroku. The project builds and runs just fine locally.
When deploying on Heroku: the build process finishes successfully. When I go to the URL of my project the home page loads successfully. However, this is the only page I can access as all other routes other than "/" produce a 404 page no found error.

What I have tried: I did online research and added the following static.json file to the root of my directory:

```
{
 "root": "build/",
 "error_page": "error.html",
 "clean_urls": false,
 "https_only": true,
 "routes": {
   "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

I have tried moving this folder down 1 directory level into my frontend folder - no luck. My React App.js file looks as follows:

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
              <Route exact path="/add" component={AddEmployee} />
              <Route exact path="/view" component={Table} />
              <Route exact path="/search" component={Search} />
              <Route exact path="/searchres" component={SearchResults} />
              <Route exact path="/delete" component={Delete} />
              <Route exact path="/update" component={UpdateEmployee} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My webpack.config.js file looks as follows:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'); // eslint-disable-line

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV;   // eslint-disable-line
var filename = 'ethjs-util';      // eslint-disable-line
var library = 'ethUtil';          // eslint-disable-line
var config = {                    // eslint-disable-line
 module: {
 loaders: [
   {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['babel-loader'],
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  },
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: 'json',
  },
],
},
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
output: {
  path: 'dist',
  filename: filename + '.js',       // eslint-disable-line
  library: library,                 // eslint-disable-line
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  umdNamedDefine: true,
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.BannerPlugin({ banner: ' /* eslint-disable */ ', raw:   
    true, entryOnly: true }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env),
  }),
 ],
};

if (env === 'production') {
  config.output.filename = filename + '.min.js'; // eslint-disable- 
   line
  config.plugins
  .push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compressor: {
      pure_getters: true,
      unsafe: true,
      unsafe_comps: true,
      warnings: false,
      screw_ie8: false,
    },
    mangle: {
      screw_ie8: false,
    },
    output: {
      screw_ie8: false,
    },
  }));
  config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin());
}

module.exports = config;
```

I understand that Heroku has specific configurations for React routes, and I tried to follow the guidelines with static.json file but still getting the 404 error. Will be happy to provide any additional information. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you share your `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: Just updated the post, hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: have you tried adding `devServer: { historyApiFallback: true }` to your configuration?

Comment: Add it to web pack.config.js file? No, let me try.

Comment: at the same structural level as your `output, plugins, devtool...`

Comment: I just tried it and it did not seem to make any difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211036/discussion-between-edgar-henriquez-and-alexander-nenartovich).